# How to iterate a HashMap using the natural entrySet() order?

Tags: java, collections

My Map contains keys sorted in alphabetical order. When I display it, I'm using entrySet().iterator(), but my results are not in the alphabetical order.
How can I get my results in order?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> A Red-Black tree based [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) implementation. The map is sorted according to the [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) of its keys, or by a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used...

Comment: Thank you Kan, just by simple replacing my HashMap with TreeMap, it worked great. thanks a lot

Answer (score 15):

No, your map does not hold elements in alphabetical order. You may have `.put(..)` then in that order, but the map does not have a defined iteration order.

Others suggest using `SortedSet`, but you can also use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). It guarantees iteration order:

> This implementation (LinkedHashMap) spares its clients from the unspecified, generally chaotic ordering provided by HashMap (and Hashtable), without incurring the increased cost associated with TreeMap

Comment: LinkedHashMap is what I needed, to keep the same order in which I inserted my items into the map.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone finding this question in 2020 and beyond...
Now that we have streams, you can do something like this:

```
map.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

> My Map contains keys sorted in alphabetical order

This is not true.

Use http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html or sort your keys before iterate

Answer (score 1):

Since `HashMap` uses hashing to store the entries in an underlying container, you aren't guaranteed any specific order.  If you want your entries from your `HashMap` ordered, you must sort them yourself.

A `TreeMap` on the other hand will maintain some sort of order (you can dictate that yourself by implementing the `Comparable` interface), so if you get its entry set, it will come to you alphabetically.  `String` already implements `Comparable`, so they will be returned to you in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) or [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).